# Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window'

Tags: javascript, jquery, utf-8, base64

Estoy enviando la siguiente cadena "Búsqueda no encontrada" al enviarla sin la ú la toma perfectamente, pero cuando va con ú sale el siguiente error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.

El codigo js es el siguiente:

```
 w._getParameterByName = function (name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : atob(decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")));
};
```

Agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que tanto `atob` como `btoa` solo admiten caracteres que ocupan 1 byte y `ú` es un caracter utf8 de 16 bits, es decir, ocupa 2 bytes y genera el error.

Si puedes codificar correctamente, pero el problema es al decodificar, es probable que se deba a la forma en que lo estás haciendo, tal vez baste con colocar `atob` dentro:

```
return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(atob(results[1]).replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

La solución propuesta por [Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa#Unicode_Strings) es codificar la cadena, de forma que se pueda asegurar que todos los caracteres ocupen solo 1 byte:

```js
// Convertir cadena Unicode a cadena donde cada
// elemento 16-bit ocupe solo un byte
function toBinary(string) {
  const codeUnits = new Uint16Array(string.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < codeUnits.length; i++) {
    codeUnits[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(codeUnits.buffer));
}

// Recodificar cadena original
function fromBinary(binary) {
  const bytes = new Uint8Array(binary.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return String.fromCharCode(...new Uint16Array(bytes.buffer));
}

// Cadena que contiene caracteres que ocupan más de 1 byte
const myString = "Búsqueda no encontrada";

// Primero se "escapan" los caracteres especiales
const converted = toBinary(myString);
// Después ya se puede codificar a base64
const encoded = btoa(converted);
console.log(encoded); // QgD6AHMAcQB1AGUAZABhACAAbgBvACAAZQBuAGMAbwBuAHQAcgBhAGQAYQA=

// Primero de codificas de base64
const decoded = atob(encoded);
// "Recuperar" caracteres especiales
const original = fromBinary(decoded);
console.log(original);  // Búsqueda no encontrada
```

### Actualización:

Si estás codificando en base64 desde PHP la opción puede ser bastante sencilla:

```
<?php
// Convierte primero a ISO-6859-1 y codifica en base 64
echo base64_encode(utf8_decode('Búsqueda no encontrada'));
// Salida: QvpzcXVlZGEgbm8gZW5jb250cmFkYQ==
```

Luego, con javascript solo usas `atob()` para recuperar la cadena original:

```js
console.log(atob('QvpzcXVlZGEgbm8gZW5jb250cmFkYQ=='));
```

Comment: En caso tal que la cadena ya venga decodificada por base64_encode en php, hay alguna forma de hacer esto mismo? gracias

Comment: Desde PHP tienes que cambiar la codificación de la cadena. Revisa la actualización.